# Dynamically load audio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I'm trying to implement TTS from Elevenlabs for a chatbot. I'm using React and Express to handle the request. I receive the request and write it to an audio file named audio.mp3. I then send the file name as the response and then save that file name in a use state variable. For every request, I modify the current audio.mp3 file with the new audio.

```
app.post("/labs", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const message = req.body.message;
    const voice = req.body.voice;
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/${voice}`,
      { text: message },
      {
        headers: {
          accept: "audio/mpeg",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "xi-api-key": config.ELVN_API_KEY,
        },
        responseType: "stream",
      }
    );
    if (response.status !== 200)
      throw new Error("Oops, something unexpected happened.");

    response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("../client/public/audio.mp3"));
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ file: "audio.mp3" }));
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

I then use the variable if it's not null.

```
{audio && <audio key={cacheBuster} autoPlay controls src={audio} />}
```

The first time I get back a response the audio works. However, any subsequent requests don't work and use the first version of the file. I've attempted to implement a cachebuster because I recognize that the browser is using the cached version of the file but it's not working for me and I've also tried .load but I'm using Typescript and I got not a function error. I don't want to create new files for every request because I want to deploy the site and I'm not sure how that would affect it performance-wise. I'm also not sure if those files are only stored for the session. If anyone has any information about that or any suggestions on how to accomplish this problem better I would greatly appreciate it.